# Applying Workbook_SheetChange to one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I found the below code I'm trying to adapt, however it seems that it runs on every worksheet within my workbook, and I only want it to apply to "Sheet3". I've tried pasting it into the Sheet3 code module, but that didn't seem to work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim TimeStr As String

    On Error GoTo EndMacro
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:a15")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .HasFormula = False Then
            Select Case Len(.Value)
                Case 1 ' e.g., 1 = 00:01 AM
                    TimeStr = "00:0" & .Value
                Case 2 ' e.g., 12 = 00:12 AM
                    TimeStr = "00:" & .Value
                Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 7:35 AM
                    TimeStr = Left(.Value, 1) & ":" & _
                    Right(.Value, 2)
                Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12:34
                    TimeStr = Left(.Value, 2) & ":" & _
                    Right(.Value, 2)
                Case Else
                    Err.Raise 0
            End Select
            .Value = Format(TimeValue(TimeStr), "hh:mm")
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

EndMacro:
    MsgBox "You did not enter a valid time"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to check which sheet is the active sheet when the function runs.  If it is the sheet you want run the code, if not exit.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro with individual [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macros.

You could isolate the existing Workbook_SheetChange by wrapping the code in something like this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If sh.Name = "Sheet3" Then
        'all of the rest of the code
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternately, put the code into the **Sheet3** worksheet code page and change the sub to this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'all of the rest of the code
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I knew it was something easy. Brain's not working after spending the last 8 hours looking at different macros and spread sheets.